# protobuf is an alternative to existing python wrappers like ctypes/SWIG/cython?

Tags: swig, ctypes, protobuf-net, cpython

I came across **protobuf** [doc](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto) Quite confused about its usage. Can we use protobuf as a replacement for ctype/swig/cython ? My requirement is have to write a python wrapper around existing user-space C library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **no**, because protofub is for data (de)serialization, it only wraps and generates POD-like structures.